# How to Improve an Elastic Net Model?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, modeling, linear-model, elastic-net

I have a dataset with $n=1500$ observations and $p=2700$ variables. 
I fitted an Elastic Net model with $\alpha=0.4$ and $\lambda=0.1$ 
I chose the $\lambda$ with cross validation, and the $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ values that gave the lowest RMSE (0.88 for the test set).

from the plot of observed vs predicted the model is not a great fit.
[image]

How can I improve my model?

Comment: This could be a problem of scaling your variables (incorrectly).

Comment: I used the R function of glmnet, which standardizes the variables. I also try to standardize on my own and set standardize=False, but got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Your model seems to be systematically biased: it systematically overpredicts small actuals, and underpredicts large actuals. To be honest, I am a bit surprised this would happen in your setup.

One way to address this is to use a very simple second model. Feed it the actual outcome as the target variable, and the fits/predictions of your elastic net as the only predictor. Based on your plots, I would assume this second model (which could be as simple as a linear regression) will give you a positive coefficient, so it will reduce low predictions and increase large predictions.

Comment: Do you mean $Y \sim predict(model)$ ?  the plot looks a bit better. but, is there a way to change the original model to fit better?

Comment: Yes, I do. As I wrote, your plot is not what I expect from an Elastic Net, so with Arya I suspect some bug.